# Not able to display results in a table using JTable

Tags: java, jdbc, jtable

I have a button called ‘View Records’. The idea is that when I click it, it displays all the records from the database in a table. 
I am able to retrieve the records from the database and display them using System.out.println or JOptionPane.showMessageDialog functions however when trying to display it using a Jtable, I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.
I am new to Java and trying to teach some to myself, but I’ve been stuck at this for some time. Help would be much appreciated.

```
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

JTable employee_table;

class home extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click)

if(click.getSource()==view_records)
  {

     try
     {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           Connection connect=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://privatedb/employee","sava","123456");
           Statement stmt=connnect.createStatement();
           ResultSet rsemp = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM employee");
employee_table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rsemp));

}
catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} finally {
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Looking at this code, the empoyye_table seems to be null. but maybe you are setting it somewhere else?

Comment: I doubt we can help you much with your question and code as currently written. It appears that you have a magic static method, `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(...)` that we don't have access to. It is kind of critical to the question, don't you think? Edit: and 1+ @user2310289's comment. It looks like your JTable will be null.

Comment: It currently displays null, however the database does contain records which I am able to display using a message box. When using the employee_table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rsemp)); line instead it fails.

Comment: I believe `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(...)` is in the Apache [DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/) library.

Comment: @peeskillet: and back at you! And 1+ to your DocumentFilter answer by the way.

Answer (score 2):

1. This is not a Swing problem but a Java problem -- you can't work with variables if they are null. You first need to assign objects to them.
2. So if you get a `NullPointerException`, look at that line and then check to see which variable you're trying to use on that line and fix it.
3. Here you need to create a new `JTable` and assign it to the `JTable` variable.
4. Keep studying and keep reading. Consider studying basic *Java* first, and then moving to *Swing* later.
5. In the future, if you have similar problems, post your error messages with your question, show which line in your code is causing the error (the error/exception message will tell you).

Answer (score 0):

1. first of all u have to  download a library file rs2xml.jar(easily available).
2. put/include it into ur application library
3. import the library file by
       import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;
4. connect to the database by

   ```
   private void connecting()  {

   try
     {

     JavaDBConnectivity dbobj=new JavaDBConnectivity();

     conn=dbobj.Connect();
     }
   catch(Exception e){

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e );
     }
   }
   ```

   // i hope u have a created a class for connecting to database(JavaDBConnectivity       here)

u can create a  button then add an event on mouseclick(use netbeans to do it easily)

```
    private void submit_queryMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          


    try{ 
         connecting();
       //  String query ="select * from "database name""; //use this or if u have text area for entering use the below statement                    
          String query=QueryArea.getText(); 

         pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);

         rs = pst.executeQuery();
         s.append (QueryArea.getText()).append("\n");
         jTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));



       }
      catch(Exception e){

          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e );
     } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

after getting the ResultSet rsemp, use the following code

```
DefaultTableModel dtm=(DefaultTableModel) employee_table.getModel();

 while(rsemp.next()){

   Vector v1=new Vector();

//in the below manner do this for all the columns in ur table

   v1.add(rsemp.getString("column1Name"));

   v1.add(rsemp.getString("column2Name"));

//after adding like that

dtm.addRow(v1);

}
```